# What happens if two python scripts want to write in the same file?

Tags: python, file, io

I have a pipeline which at some point splits work into various sub-processes that do the same thing in parallel. Thus their output should go into the same file.

Is it too risky to say all of those processes should write into the same file? Or does python try and retry if it sees that this resource is occupied?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, this is not a good idea and will take a lot of care to get right. Since the writes will have to be serialized, it might also adversely affect scalability.

I'd recommend writing to separate files and merging (or just leaving them as separate files).

Comment: Oh ok! How can it affect scalability? You mean if suddenly a lot of processes want to write into the same file and hold each other up?

Comment: @dmeu: That's basically it. If you have multiple processes wanting to write at the same time, only one of them will be able to, and the rest will just sit there waiting instead of doing useful work.

Answer (score 12):

This is system dependent. In Windows, the resource is locked and you get an exception. In Linux you can write the file with two processes (written data could be mixed)

Ideally in such cases you should use **semaphores** to synchronize access to shared resources.

If using semaphores is too heavy for your needs, then the only alternative is to write in separate files...

**Edit**: As pointed out by eye in [a later post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820021/what-happens-if-two-python-scripts-want-to-write-in-the-same-file/7820272#7820272), a resource manager is another alternative to handle concurrent writers

Answer (score 3):

A better solution is to implement a resource manager (writer) to avoid opening the same file twice. This manager could use threading synchronization mechanisms (`threading.Lock`) to avoid simultaneous access on some platforms.

Comment: Ok i will have to look into this option. This will also work on a cluster, right? meaning on a system where the calculations are made on different computers, but share the filesystem where they write their results

Answer (score 2):

How about having all of the different processes write their output into a queue, and have a single process that reads that queue, and writes to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Use multiprocessing.Lock() instead of threading.Lock(). Just a word of caution! might slow down your concurrent processing ability because one process just waits for the lock to be released